# Storing scraped data from multiple web pages in a single variable in console using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I am trying to build a scraper to scrape product reviews from the amazon site. Till now I have become able to scrape and download reviews from a single page. My real aim is to scrape all reviews from multiple pages and store these scraped reviews in a single variable and download them at once rather than scraping and downloading them one by one page. Please help me with how can I store this scraped data from multiple pages in a single variable.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways to scrape Amazon product reviews is to use an NPM package [`ecommerce-scraper-js`](https://github.com/dimitryzub/ecommerce-scraper-js).

To use this package, first, you need to add it to your Node.js project:

```bash
npm i ecommerce-scraper-js
```

Then import it and call the `getListingInfo` method with `amazon`, specify the link to the desired product in the method arguments, then `undefined` twice (if you do not want to change the default currency and language), and the last argument is the number of reviews you want to get:

```js
import { amazon } from "ecommerce-scraper-js";

amazon
  .getListingInfo(
    "https://www.amazon.com/PlayStation-5-Console-CFI-1215A01X/dp/B0BCNKKZ91/", // product link
    undefined, // currency argument
    undefined, // language argument
    1000 // number of reviews to get
  )
  .then((result) => console.log(result.reviewsInfo?.reviews));
```

Output:

```json
[
   {
      "name":"Pat Mice",
      "avatar":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/S/amazon-avatars-global/c9471951-505f-46b7-87e3-13562de200f3._CR109,0,281,281_SX48_.jpg",
      "rating":5,
      "summary":"Wow!  Exceeds Expectations",
      "dateAndPlace":"Reviewed in the United States  on May 11, 2023",
      "bage":"Verified Purchase",
      "review":"+ Controller design is sleek ... smaller buttons. Easier to hit what you want.+ Share, Options and PS buttons have a profile. No more groping for them. (Hate the flush
PS4 buttons.)+ The on-screen keyboard is greatly improved. Much easier & faster.+ And finally ... the graphics. *chef's kiss*  It's like I have a new TV. Not exaggerating. Vibrant & crisp. I wasn't prepared for how beautiful games look. Didn't touch TV settings. Just plugged in the PS5 and voila! Games that I always had trouble with reading text are a thing of the past. Everything on screen is crystal clear.Had the PS5 shipped in Amazon packing for obvious reasons but was uneasy based on comments.  Was sitting outside waiting when the driver arrived and placed the box next to me.  The tape was mostly pulled away from the top flaps. One side of the box was torn and the PS5 box was clearly visible.  My heart sank. Happily, I received a pristine PS5.  The Sony box doesn't have a mark or dent on it. The seal was intact and everything inside was untouched. (Sadly, the literature is in Spanish & French only.  Oops!)  The console booted normally and plays discs perfectly. Encountered none of the issues others recently described.This is truly money well spent. If you game a lot and want a better experience but haven't managed to pull the trigger, I say go for it!  I'm so happy with this console. It's absolutely better than PS4 and not just a little bit. I've been very happy with my PS4 and didn't expect wonders but the PS5 is a significant step up.==============================================================================TIPSIf your brand new PS5 isn't reading discs, don't panic. The optical scanner is on the outside of the slot, meaning that you must face the label in towards the console. For most people,
it's counterintuitive. I unwittingly put the first disc in backwards and thought I had a console with a bad reader.  Nope.  It works fine.The UI on the PS5 is NOT like PS4.  If you
can't seem to get to the main menu, which they call the Control Center, hit the PS button twice.  (some screens only require that you press it once)Do not put your PS5 on a base with 'cooling fans' in it.  The PS5 pulls air in at the top and vents at the bottom. Bases with fans blow the hot air up and overheat the console. PS5 definitely does not run as hot as PS4. As long as there's breathing space around the PS5, it should be fine.Crashing - It's not constant but there's no way around it, especially if you're playing games that were originally created for PC. While PS5 is better than PS4 at rendering graphics, no PlayStation has the chops to render graphics like PCs with high end GPUs. The only PS games that have ever crashed on me are PC games that were ported to PlayStation. Happily, I've never lost data due to crashes."
   },
   {
      "name":"User",
      "avatar":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/x-locale/common/grey-pixel.gif",
      "rating":5,
      "summary":"Disc Over Digital, Great Bundle",
      "dateAndPlace":"Reviewed in the United States  on April 29, 2023",
      "bage":"Verified Purchase",
      "review":"When I saw this for $510, essentially getting $50-$60 off God of War Ragnarok, I was very happy. I missed the original PS4 era and only recently got one second-hand to
play all the Playstation exclusives. I blasted through them all and then was ready for PS5 exclusives like Rift Apart.-Having been a past digital-only console owner on the Xbox side, I will say this -- I believe in the advantages of physical games. Yes, most game disks currently only hold an access key to play a game and not the actual files for the game itself, BUT having a disk means having more options. You can resell a disk. You can hold it physically in your hand. You can trade it with friends. And, sort of a big thing -- if you ever lose your account for some reason, YOU DON'T LOSE ALL THE DIGITAL GAMES tied to your account.-My advice is don't get sucked into digital gaming just because it's cheaper to initially get a Series S or a digital PS5. You won't physically own any license keys to the games if you go digital. If Microsoft of PS5 servers or accounts ever go down, all your stuff gets lost. They already hold our game saves hostage -- remember when you used to be able to put saves on a flashdrive and not have them tied to your account? -- so don't let them hold your actual games hostage, too. This is my advice for a lot of media nowadays. Buy hard copies. Movies, music, games, books -- all of it. Otherwise, you're essentially paying ownership-level prices to rent electronically.-Why am I fine with a digital code for Ragnarok in this bundle? It is annoying -- I'd rather have a disk, BUT you can't get a disk for this game right now at the price of $10 (assuming you buy this bundle at the sale price of $510). If you're itching to play Ragnarok right now and feel like it's the right time to upgrade, this is the best deal. I imagine Ragnarok won't ever be on sale for $10 -- PS4 God of War still sells for like $20 by comparison, so this bundle is a great deal.-Not Amazon's fault, but I feel iffy about the white plastic. It looks cool and futuristic, but white plastic can get gross over time. I would suggest keeping the console and controller out of direct sunlight and having regular (gentle) cleanings. Not sure how I feel about protective decals at this time, but that middle black plastic bar of the console scratches super easily, so I'd say maybe consider a center decal sooner rather than later.--My console arrived neatly, not really anything to note. One white panel on it seems to have a faint scratch or mould mark, but it didn't really bother me or take away from the PS5 experience.-Hope this helps you all! Trying to give my honest opinion as someone who adores all sorts of games and all sorts of consoles. Good luck!"
   },
   ... and other reviews
]
```

> Disclaimer: I'm author of this package

Comment: This does not work as you claim. Somehow Amazon limits the number of pages with reviews to 10 pages, so that you can scrape only up to a maximum of 100 reviews and not your specified number of reviews.